# RabbitMQ queue publish access refused

Tags: javascript, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-stomp

Setting permission for a user to only grant publish to a particular queue **Q1**

Permission

Configure : ""

Write : **^(Q1)|(amqp.default)$**

Read : ""

Protocol used : **STOMP**

RMQ version : **3.6.X**

Access is refused when publishing to **Q1** using above permissions.

If Configure is set to **^(Q1)$** it works without any issues. But setting configure permission will also allow user to queue.delete and queue.declare operations on **Q1**.

Case : Create a queue from the backend/RMQ management so that stomp clients can publish to it through direct amqp.default exchange and routing key as the queue name. So that client has only write permission to the queue, without configure or read permissions

What would be the best solution for the same if a user is required only to publish to a queue but not read or configure the queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, remember that you publish to **exchanges** in RabbitMQ, not queues. Then, read [this table](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html#permissions) to determine how configure, write and read permission applies to the operations you'd like to do.

Finally, since the STOMP plugin is used, the user must have `configure` permission to be able to create the reply queue. This is due to how STOMP is implemented in RabbitMQ ([code](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-stomp/blob/00c9fff6229a8af90339b57250b7d45ed694fda8/src/rabbit_stomp_processor.erl#L873-L884)).

Comment: I understand that we publish to an exchanges and not to queues hence write permission is granted with amqp.default since **amqp.default** is the exchange and **Q1** would be the routing key. So message is published to default exchange and routed to the routing key. Why are configure permission required for the routing key when write permission are set?

Comment: The exchange name is `amq.default` for the default direct exchange. If your code tries to declare the queue, it will need the configure permission. I suspect your issue has to do with not using the correct exchange name and trying to declare the queue (which does require configure permission)

Comment: A durable queue has been already generated through backend code / rabbitmq management ui so that client(JavaScript) has to just publish to the default exchange using routing key.So that client does not have to configure or create the queue. All clients will have write permission to this queue but no configure or read permission.
Example using stomp

 

    ```var client = Stomp.over(ws)
    client.send('/queue/Q1',{ "content-type": "text/plain" }, 'Hello');```

Comment: It would have been helpful to mention that you are using the stomp protocol, via the `rabbitmq-web-stomp` plugin I assume. The way the STOMP protocol is implemented in RabbitMQ ([code](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-stomp/blob/00c9fff6229a8af90339b57250b7d45ed694fda8/src/rabbit_stomp_processor.erl#L873-L884)) requires configure permission to create the reply queue.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the protocol used. Thanks for the link, any reason why its different in stomp as compared to other protocols?

Comment: Update your answer with the configure permission required for STOMP, will mark as answer for future reference.

Comment: I'm pretty sure MQTT does something similar. It all comes down to mapping STOMP and other protocol semantics onto AMQP. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**STOMP** protocol requires configure permission, so had to come up with a different approach.([RabbitMQ code](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-stomp/blob/00c9fff6229a8af90339b57250b7d45ed694fda8/src/rabbit_stomp_processor.erl#L873-L884))

Created an exchange **E1** and granted user with **write** permission

Bind queue **Q1** to **E1** so every message published to **E1** is routed to **Q1**

In this approach only write permissions are required by the STOMP client to publish to exchange **E1** without read or configure permission